# Pull instead of push for alerts escalartion in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

We have network configuration where it's very inconvenient for local Alertmanagers to push alerts to the deduplicating central Alertmanager.

I wonder if there is a pull method for alerts escalation in Alertmanager, and if it is, how to enable it?

Comment: what makes it inconvinient to push? why are the prometheuses not in the same Network then the alertmanager(s)

Comment: We have central AM on central servers, and there is a policy (enforced by firewalls), that central server is visiting all peripheral servers, not peripheral servers connecting to central one. Normal prom scraping is perfectly aligned with this model, but escalation aren't. Networks are different because servers are physically on different continents.

Comment: So youre saying, you have prometheus instances running in a central place but the alertmanagers are not?

Comment: Opposite. We have distributed prometheuses with own alertmanagers, and we want to have a centralized alertmanager to provide an overview of all alerts in the system. Normally it's done by escalation from local AM to centralized AM, but we really would like to avoid 'push' here and use pull from central AM toward local AMs.

Comment: Or simply rethink your network configuration :)  maybe it would help to have a central alert manager cluster and allow all prometheus instances to push their alerts to these instances.